# Python Download csv files from url but get Connection Error

Tags: python, csv, url

I am trying to download a csv file from the website using Python3 and this is my code:

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv

url = "http://www.cnac.ca/data/COCodeStatus_NPA204.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    reader = csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print (row)
```

The error message is:

> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>
> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.cnac.ca', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /data/COCodeStatus_NPA204.csv (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

How can I work around / fix / debug this?

Comment: I am able to download this file using this code.

Comment: I can also run this code, except I had to decode the bytes first with `lines = (line.decode('utf8') for line in r.iter_lines())`. Can you do a plain `requests.get(url)`? Can you access the URL in a browser?

Comment: 11004 is `WSANO_DATA` usually meaning a DNS name was resolved but its DNS record didn't have any data. To narrow down, see if `socket.getaddrinfo('www.cnac.ca', 80)` has the same problem. So, you've got a broken DNS somehow. Could be local cash or maybe you need to go through a proxy or whereever you are at there is a firewall blocking you.

Comment: This isn't a problem with your program. I think you will have better luck rewording the question a bit and posting on serverfault.com.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I have figured out that it is because of the corporate firewall. I disconnect VPN and connect my wifi it worked.